# usar <p:galleria> con imagenes que no estan en el proyecto sino en el disco local

Tags: imagen, primefaces

Tengo un problema al usar  con imagenes que no estan en el proyecto sino en el disco local, el p:galleria aparece con 4 cuadritos (por las 4 imagenes) pero esta en blanco y me muestra el alt a pesar de que en la carpeta si estan las imagenes

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
 template="/WEB-INF/templates/layoutnormal.xhtml">

    <h:form id="form">
 <p:galleria id="galeria" value="#{bean.listaImagenes}" var="image" panelWidth="400" panelHeight="313" showCaption="true"> 
<p:graphicImage name="#{image}" title="#{image}" alt="#{image}" /> </p:galleria> 
</h:form> 
</ui:composition>
```

Bean.java

```
@ManagedBean(name = "bean")
@ViewScoped
public class Bean extends GenericBean implements Serializable {
List<String> listaImagenes = new ArrayList<>();

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
listaImagenes.add("C:/fotos/img/img1.png");
listaImagenes.add("C:/fotos/img/img2.png");
listaImagenes.add("C:/fotos/img/img3.png");
listaImagenes.add("C:/fotos/img/img4.png");
}
}
```

Comment: Si estan en el servidor, tendras que usar una ruta que el servidor reconozca. Si estan en el cliente, es imposible.

Comment: @JDev se puede de algun modo copiar las imagenes del cliente al servidor y al terminar la vista las elimine?

Comment: Sin interaccion del cliente no.

Comment: La solución fue que creara una copia de la imagen en la carpeta resources del war y mandarla llamar desde ahí